# Подключение ODBC+Oracle+Qt

Tags: oracle, qt5, odbc

Итак, имеется:
Oracle 11g Express Edition x64
Qt 5.11.0 + MinGW x32 + MSVC2015 x64 (Даже студия 2015 есть)
Win7 x64

Теперь к проблеме, необходимо подключить проект к оракловой БД через ODBC
При сборке через MinGW и настройке ODBC через администрирование имеем ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При настройке ODBC через odbcad32.exe из SysWOW64, ошибка такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ну а если собирать проект через MSVC, то ошибка следующая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как все же подключить проект к БД? В какую сторону копать? Какой из косяков исправлять в первую очередь?

```
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC", "XE");
db.setHostName("localhost"); //-
db.setPort(1521); //-
db.setDatabaseName("XE"); //+
db.setUserName("system"); //+
db.setPassword("2608"); //+
if (!db.open())
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "HEOK",db.lastError().text());
} else QMessageBox::information(this, "OK", "KRUTO!");
```

Comment: Порядок настройки ODBC и код подключения к БД в студию. Через MSVC не компилируется потому, что комплект QT для MinGW скомпилирован, нужен комплект для MSVC

Comment: @tequillaz   код добавил в вопрос, комплект для MSVC стоит, вроде как даже не ругается ни на что

Comment: Драйвер настраивали 32-х или 64-х битный?

Comment: Насчет MSVC, сами же писали что при сборке ошибка. qmake настроен на mingw, а инструмент для сборки - студийный

Comment: @tequillaz настраивал оба драйвера: х32 ругается на архитектуру, х64 на отсутствие СУБД. Я не так давно с Qt, поэтому прошу немного прояснить про настройку qmake, настроенного набор под 15 студию не достаточно?

Comment: Mingw собирает 32-х битную программу, другие он не умеет. Судя по описанию ошибки со снимка №1, поставленный и настроенный драйвер -
 для 64-битной архитектуры. Судя по описанию ошибки со снимка №2 и справки отсюда https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/942976, odbcad32.exe из SysWOW64 настраивает 32-х битный драйвер, которого у Вас нет, либо для него не хватает каких-то компонентов, о чем и написано на снимке. Что же касается компилятора MSVC, так ему нужен комплект qt, скомпилированный с помощью MSVC; комплект, скомпилированный для mingw, с MSVC работать не будет.

Comment: @tequillaz спасибо за подробный ответ, попробую привести все к одной битности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил: Проект собираю через MinGW x32, СУБД так же сделал x32.
Про драйвер: удалил старый через менеджер который лежит в **SysWOW64**, иначе он ругается на отсутствие неких инсталляторов, после чего добавил через менеджер из администрирования, там проблем не возникло.